# Set timeout to mpi process launch

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing, mpich

When I run mpi program on multiple hosts, if executable failed to start on any of the host (due to missing library etc. type of reasons), other hosts just keep waiting for the process to come up. The program just hangs forever. Is there any way to set a timeout in such cases such that MPI should abort if not all processes were launched in a given timeout period?

Thanks

Edit: 
I came up with following solution to spawn up a new thread before mpi_init with future/promise paradigm. I'm still open to better solution.

```
int main() {
  std::promise<std::string> mpi_launch_promise;
  std::future<std::string> mpi_launch_future = mpi_launch_promise.get_future();

  // Separate thread is launched which makes sure mpi is initialized in specified time limit.
  std::thread mpi_launch_thread(
    [](std::future<std::string>& current_host, const int& timeout = 2) {
    auto status = current_host.wait_for(std::chrono::minutes(timeout));
    if (status == std::future_status::timeout) {
      // exit program with error message
    } else if (status == std::future_status::ready) {
      // notify success of mpi launch
    }
  }, std::ref(mpi_launch_future), 2 /* wait 2 min*/);
  mpi_launch_thread.detach();

  MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

  // Notify success of mpi_init to mpi_launch_thread
  mpi_launch_promise.set_value(/*send hostname*/);
}
```

Comment: Would you be so kind to tell which MPI implementation you use? Did you consult the man page for mpirun or mpiexec?

Comment: I'm using MPICH implementation. Yes, I did consult manpages for mpirun and mpiexec. Thanks!